# Limit the number of objects to a particular number in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket in which I store certain build outputs. I am looking to keep the contents in there to a particular number. So far, all I have seen is that there is no limit to the number of objects that can be stored in an S3 bucket but none on how to limit them to a particular number. Does AWS provide that option?

Comment: What would you want to happen when it exceeds that number? Should it prevent adding new objects, or should it delete old objects (and how would you specify which ones to delete)? While S3 doesn't have such a capability, you could easily build it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an option on a bucket to do that.  However, it would be pretty simple to create a Lambda function that listens to S3 bucket events and reacts accordingly - in your case, perhaps deleting old files.  [This tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) walks through an example scenario that sends S3 events to a Lambda function.

Comment: I was able to write a Lambda function that is able to do this!! Thanks!